# Which is more efficient? duplifaces, particles, or group instances?

Tags: rendering, performance, memory-management, instances

Particles give more controls for doing things like randomizing rotation of instances, but duplifaces and group instances allow for rotation and scale of individual instances.

For something like creating a forest with a lot of trees, is it more efficient to use a particle system? Or a dupliface object?

What is the most efficient way to instantiate a large number of objects?

---

*By "efficient" I mean in terms of rendertime/memory usage.*

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the specifics of Blender's implementation. But, it seems to me, they would use the exact same algorithm in both cases. With particle instancing, you have a position vector and a transformation matrix for each particle. The only difference with dupliface is the position vector is determined by an object's face, rather than a particle.

So, memory is going to be the same. Render time should be the same, unless you're using extra features. For example, you can have objects deform along a particle's path when using particle instancing. The deformations would take extra time to compute when rendering.

Comment: Deformations should only increase _Building_ time, not _Render_ time.

Comment: @someonewithpc building BVH is done for rendering, so you could arguably consider it as part of render time..

Comment: @gandalf3 but if you use Cache BVH, it skips building and just renders...

Comment: @someonewithpc True.. But only only if nothing changes. But whether it's *building* time or *render* time is pretty trivial imo. Doesn't really matter :P

Comment: @gandalf3 No, it doesn't, really. :D